# QUERY - GROUP BY counting different clients by date

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Data sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DDs2PvljSsY0jD0v2VmM0NsGkJmhoBPKOXvln9d1MTw/edit?usp=sharing

Above is a link to a spreadsheet where I have a sample of the data I'm working with.
I need to do a query where i can count how many different clients I attended that day. Example (INFO column not needed as a result, just a helper here for me to describe what I need):

| DATE | COUNT(DIFFERENT CLIENTS) | INFO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/01/2021 | 3 | "Fleury Campinas", "SEDI II AME SOROCABA", "Hospital Santa Catarina" |
| 06/01/2021 | 2 | "Hospital e Maternidade Metropolitano Lapa", "Fleury A+ Morumbi" |

Can you help me?

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet containing the data shown in your post, so that the volunteer contributors here have something to start with. It is also important to have *your* sheet, because everything from your international locale to your data formatting will affect how a formula might be written.

Comment: Edited with a link to the sample, ty for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the layout of the actual data and the locale of Brazil, I added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with this formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"DATE"\"UNIQUE CLIENTS"\"INFO";{QUERY(UNIQUE({'Query from Data'!B5:B\'Query from Data'!E5:E});"Select Col1, COUNT(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col2) ''")\REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({'Query from Data'!B5:B\'Query from Data'!E5:E&","}; "Select MAX(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1");; 9^9)));"^\S+\s*|[,\s]+$";"");",\s*";CHAR(10))}})`

This is complex, and explaining it in full would take far longer than writing it. So I am offering it as-is, inviting anyone who is interested to take it apart and see what each part does alone and collectively.

The short version:

Headers are created.

Under those, there is a virtual array formed of a two-column QUERY to the left of another one-column QUERY. The first returns unique dates and counts of unique clients (two columns). The second combines each date with the unique client list for that date and then uses REGEX-type commands to get rid of the date portion and to replace comma-space with a line return `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: Definitely worked. When I grow up, I want to have that knowledge you have hahaha ty once again

Comment: It's really not about "growing up," Gabriel. We each know things other people don't know (or don't know yet, or don't know as well). And anyone who knows anything about anything learned it essentially the same way: from the beginning, and one piece at a time. So you are as capable of knowing what I know as anyone else is. Keep with it!

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the unique values in the first and third columns then grouping by date using a query:

```
=query(unique({A:A,C:C}),"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1")
```

[image]